# Giving error while using varchar field in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table
Both the id and value are varchars

```
>> id          "value"
-----------------------
   a             1
   a             2
   a             5
   a             6
   a             7
   a             8
   b             4
   b             5
   b             6
   b             9
```

I just want to see the output

```
value    Result
-----------------
a        1-2,5,6-8
b        4-6,9
```

I tried using `ListAGG()` function

Its giving the error "value" as invalid identifier

```
SELECT
      LISTAGG ( TXT,
              ', ' )
      WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "value")
          "Result"
FROM
      (SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN MIN ( "value" ) = MAX ( "value" )
                THEN
                    CAST ( MIN ( "value" ) AS VARCHAR2 ( 400 ) )
                ELSE
                       MIN ( "value" )
                    || '-'
                    || MAX ( "value" )
            END
                AS TXT,
            MIN ( "value" ) AS SOURCE
       FROM
            (SELECT
                   ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (ORDER BY MIN ( "value" ))
                   - TO_NUMBER ( "value" )
                       AS GRP
             FROM
                   TABL2)
       GROUP BY
            GRP);
```

I guess is there any type mismatch..??
can you please help me...

Comment: Do you have two accounts? [That query looks kind of familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20519350/73226)

Comment: @Martin: I dont have two Accounts... :) Its same only but i am getting the error as "value invalid identifier" my both columns are varchars..can u please help me out

Comment: Is the name of the `value` column really lower case?

Comment: If you are OK with wm_concat, then its really simple. But unfortunately its not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with the code.  But the cause of the error is that you're not including `value` in the SELECT of the subquery.

I also noticed that you're missing `PARTITION BY id`, which is required in order to do the groupings you want.  You're also not grouping by `id` in the outer query.

This query:

```
SELECT id,
      LISTAGG ( TXT,', ' )
      WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY source)"Result"
FROM
      (SELECT id,
            CASE
                WHEN MIN ( "value" ) = MAX ( "value" )
                THEN
                    CAST ( MIN ( "value" ) AS VARCHAR2 ( 400 ) )
                ELSE
                       MIN ( "value" )
                    || '-'
                    || MAX ( "value" )
            END
                AS TXT,
            MIN ( "value" ) AS SOURCE
       FROM (
            SELECT id,"value",
                   ROW_NUMBER ( )  OVER (partition by id ORDER BY MIN ( "value" ))
                   - TO_NUMBER ( "value" )
                       AS GRP
             FROM
                   TABL2
             GROUP BY id,"value"
       )
       GROUP BY
            id,GRP)
GROUP BY id
```

Produces:

```
a   1-2, 5-8
b   4-6, 9
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8a0f5/22/0)

Comment: @Joe... OP wants both column to be varchar2. What you have is a number and varchar2. Can you please check??

Comment: @realspirituals Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.  The output is inherently varchar2 due to the concat from LISTAGG.  I had originally created "value" as a NUMBER in my SQLFiddle, but changing it to varchar2 does not require any changes to the SELECT, which produces the same result either way.